# How to properly cast a global memory array using the uint4 vector in CUDA to increase memory throughput?

Tags: c, optimization, cuda

There are generally two techniques to increase the memory throughput of the global memory on a CUDA kernel on compute capability 1.3 GPUs; memory accesses coalescence and accessing words of at least 4 bytes. With the first technique accesses to the same memory segment by threads of the same half-warp are coalesced to fewer transactions while be accessing words of at least 4 bytes this memory segment is effectively increased from 32 bytes to 128.

**Update: solution based on talonmies answer**. To access 16-byte instead of 1-byte words when there are unsigned chars stored in the global memory, the uint4 vector is commonly used by casting the memory array to uint4. To get the values from the uint4 vector, it can be recasted to uchar4 as below:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

__global__ void kernel ( unsigned char *d_text, unsigned char *d_out ) {

    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    extern __shared__ unsigned char s_array[];

    uint4 *uint4_text = reinterpret_cast<uint4 *>(d_text);
    uint4 uint4_var;

    //memory transaction
    uint4_var = uint4_text[0];

    //recast data to uchar4
    uchar4 c0 = *reinterpret_cast<uchar4 *>(&uint4_var.x);
    uchar4 c4 = *reinterpret_cast<uchar4 *>(&uint4_var.y);
    uchar4 c8 = *reinterpret_cast<uchar4 *>(&uint4_var.z);
    uchar4 c12 = *reinterpret_cast<uchar4 *>(&uint4_var.w);

    d_out[idx] = c0.y;
}

int main ( void ) {

    unsigned char *d_text, *d_out;

    unsigned char *h_out = ( unsigned char * ) malloc ( 16 * sizeof ( unsigned char ) );
    unsigned char *h_text = ( unsigned char * ) malloc ( 16 * sizeof ( unsigned char ) );

    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
            h_text[i] = 65 + i;

    cudaMalloc ( ( void** ) &d_text, 16 * sizeof ( unsigned char ) );
    cudaMalloc ( ( void** ) &d_out, 16 * sizeof ( unsigned char ) );

    cudaMemcpy ( d_text, h_text, 16 * sizeof ( unsigned char ), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

    kernel<<<1,16>>>(d_text, d_out );

    cudaMemcpy ( h_out, d_out, 16 * sizeof ( unsigned char ), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

    for ( i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
            printf("%c\n", h_out[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood what you are trying to do, the logical approach is to use the C++ `reinterpret_cast` mechanism to make the compiler generate the correct vector load instruction, then use the CUDA built in byte sized vector type `uchar4` to access each byte within each of the four 32 bit words loaded from global memory. Using this approach, you are really putting trust in the compiler knowing the optimal way to do byte wise access within each 32 bit register.

A completely contrived example could look like this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

__global__
void kernel(unsigned int *in, unsigned char* out)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x;

    uint4* p = reinterpret_cast<uint4*>(in);
    uint4  i4 = p[tid]; // vector load here

    uchar4 c0 = *reinterpret_cast<uchar4 *>(&i4.x);
    uchar4 c4 = *reinterpret_cast<uchar4 *>(&i4.y);
    uchar4 c8 = *reinterpret_cast<uchar4 *>(&i4.z);
    uchar4 c12 = *reinterpret_cast<uchar4 *>(&i4.w);

    out[tid*4+0] = c0.x;
    out[tid*4+1] = c4.y;
    out[tid*4+2] = c8.z;
    out[tid*4+3] = c12.w;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int c[8] = { 
        2021161062, 2021158776, 2020964472, 1920497784, 
        2021161058, 2021161336, 2020898936, 1702393976 };

    unsigned int * _c;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&_c, sizeof(int)*size_t(8));
    cudaMemcpy(_c, c, sizeof(int)*size_t(8), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    unsigned char * _m;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&_m, sizeof(unsigned char)*size_t(8));

    kernel<<<1,2>>>(_c, _m);

    unsigned char m[8];
    cudaMemcpy(m, _m, sizeof(unsigned char)*size_t(8), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
        fprintf(stdout, "%d %c\n", i, m[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

which should produce a readable string of characters embedded in the array of unsigned integers supplied to the kernel.

One caveat is that the open64 compiler used for compute 1.x targets would often defeat this strategy of trying to generate vector loads if it could detect that not all of the words in the vector were actually used. So make sure that you touch all of the input words in the input vector type to ensure the compiler plays nicely.

Comment: Edited the question to add a working example of what i am currently doing. I am not familiar with reinterpret_cast as my code is in pure c

Comment: @charis: CUDA is a subset of C++, there is no such thing "pure C" in CUDA.

Comment: @charis: also you do understand that the casting in my sample is happening after the global memory load, as you have stressed in your latest edit?

Comment: Yes of course. I will try it out and update my question accordingly

Comment: Yes, this works. So it seems that the solution is to recast uint4 to uchar4. Interestingly i haven't seen any performance increase when substituting bitwise operations (as per the original post) with recasting (as per your post). In order to update my question, which one is better, straight recasting or using reinterpret_cast? Both of these work: `uint4 *uint4_text = ( uint4 * ) d_text` and `uint4 *uint4_text = reinterpret_cast<uint4 *>(d_text);`

Comment: @charis: the compiler is probably generating shifts internally to read out bytes from 32 bit registers. But the advantage is that it is much cleaner code using casting, and if the hardware and or compiler evolve, you (hopefully) automagically get the most performant solution without needing to change anything in your code. The two casts you are asking about are equivalent - one is a more traditional C style cast, the other the most correct C++ way to specify this style of cast. To a degree it is only personal choice.

Answer (score 3):

Casting to char* will work just fine. Did you try? If so, what happened that prompted this question?

In your example, it looks like you could just cast `s_array` to an `int*` and do a single copy from `var.x` (multiplying `j` with 4 instead of 16).

If you need more flexible shuffling of the bytes in a word, you can use the `__byte_perm()` intrinsic. For instance, to reverse the order of the bytes in the integer `x`, you can do `__byte_perm(x, 0, 0x0123);`

It may be that you won't gain anything by using the vector types, or even a single int, to store the bytes. On Fermi, global memory transactions are 128 bytes wide. So, when your warp hits an instruction that does a load/store from/to global memory, the GPU will do as many 128-byte transactions as are necessary to service the 32 threads. Performance will depend largely on how many separate transactions are necessary, not on how each thread loads or stores its bytes.

Comment: Edited the question to be more clear. In practice i can't figure out what to recast var to. Moreover, this optimization is valid for GT200 cards (a compute capability 1.3 GPU) where a memory transaction serves 32 bytes when 1-byte words are accessed from global memory